# Hierarchy of Java Classes

Tags: java

I created a model of the zoo. In my zoo I only have birds. In my main class, Zoopark, I put an animal in a cage. Currently, an unlimited number of birds can be added to the cage. But there should not be more than two birds in each cage. How do I make this revision?

Main class

```
public class Zoopark {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Bassein V1 = new Bassein();
    Bird B = new Bird("Vala", 100, true);
    V1.putAnimal(B);
    Bird C = new Bird("Lilu", 100, true);
    V1.putAnimal(C);
    Bird D = new Bird("Abara", 100, true);
    V1.putAnimal(D);

    OpenCage V2 = new OpenCage();
    Hippo E = new Hippo("Kala", 1000, true);
    V2.putAnimal(E);        
    Hippo I = new Hippo("Nala", 1000, true);
    V2.putAnimal(I);
    Hippo F = new Hippo("Mala", 1000, true);
    V2.putAnimal(F);
    Hippo U = new Hippo("Ala", 1000, true);
    V2.putAnimal(U);
}

}
```

Class with cages

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Valers {

private final static int CageLimit=2;

List<Animals> result = new ArrayList<Animals>();

public void putAnimal(Animals a) {

    int numAnimals=result.size();

    if (numAnimals>=CageLimit) { 
       System.out.println("This cage is full!");
       System.out.println(" ");
    }
    else {
       this.result.add(a);
       System.out.println("Animal added in cage");
       System.out.println("  ");
    }
}

public int getCageAnimals() {
    return result.size();
}

}
```

Bassein cage class:

```
public class Bassein extends Valers {

}
```

OpenCage cage class:

```
public class OpenCage extends Valers {

}
```

Abstract class Animal:

```
abstract public class Animals {

private String name;
private int weight;
// is this boy?
private boolean isMale;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return weight;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public boolean isMale() {
    return isMale;
}

public void setMale(boolean isMale) {
    this.isMale = isMale;
}

public Animals(String name, int weight, boolean isMale) {
    this.name = name;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.isMale = isMale;
}

}
```

Class bird:

```
public class Bird extends Animals {



public Bird(String name, int weight, boolean isMale) {
    super(name, weight, isMale);
    System.out.println(name + " " + weight + " " + isMale);
}
}
```

Class with hippos:

```
public class Hippo extends Animals {

public Hippo(String name, int weight, boolean isMale) {
    super(name, weight, isMale);
    System.out.println(name + " " + weight + " " + isMale);
}
}
```

Now this output:

```
Vala 100 true
Animal added in cage

Lilu 100 true
Animal added in cage

Abara 100 true
This cage is full!

Kala 1000 true
Animal added in cage

Nala 1000 true
Animal added in cage

Mala 1000 true
This cage is full!

Ala 1000 true
This cage is full!
```

And should be:

```
Vala 100 true
Animal added in cage

Lilu 100 true
Animal added in cage

Abara 100 true
This cage is full

Kala 1000 true
Animal added in cage

Nala 1000 true
Animal added in cage

Mala 1000 true
Animal added in cage

Ala 1000 true
Animal added in cage
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you checking the size of the cage to match your requirements?

Comment: If `Bassein` mean "cage", then what is `Valers`? If `Valers` is a "Class with cages", why does it contain animals, and not cages? And why doesn't a cage contain animals? And if `Valers` is a "Class with cages", why is `Bassein` (a "cage") a type of `Valers`?

Comment: Bassein - it is one type of cages

Answer (score 2):

Add this before adding the animal in Valers.putAnimal():

```
if (result.size() >= 2) {
    System.out.println("This cage is full!");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Okay, this right for one class Bird, but when I have got more classes, what doing?

Comment: If you have more classes but still want to have only two total animals this will be it. If you want for example two birds but still the ability to put a hippo inside you'll probably be better off iterating over the list looking for instances of birds and hippos only.

Comment: Thank you. For example, I have two classes: hippos and birds. I want the hippos to be no more than five, and the birds are not more than two. How do I know how many animals I have in a particular class?

Comment: I couldn't have phrased it better than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46478805/8517948).

Answer (score 2):

While @LW001's answer would give the proper print output, I believe that, logically, you would still have a third animal added to the cage. What may be better is for you to add a method to check the cage for # of animals. Then add an if statement to only add an animal if there's less than two animals. For instance:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Valers {

    private final static int CageLimit=2;

    List<Animals> result = new ArrayList<Animals>();

    public void putAnimal(Animals a) {

        int numAnimals=result.size();

        if (numAnimals>=CageLimit) { 
           System.out.println("This cage is full!");
           System.out.println(" ");
        }
        else {
           this.result.add(a);
           System.out.println("Animal added in cage");
           System.out.println("  ");
        }
    }

    public integer getCageAnimals() {
        return result.size();
    }
}
```

Notice that I included a `private final static int`for CageLimit. This is because good practice dictates not to include 'magic numbers' in the logic of your code. So initialize it at the start as an immutable value.

Comment: Thank you! Okay, this works for Cages in general. But when I have got besides birds there are hippos. Your method would be work for Birds and Hippos. But  I want the hippos to be no more than five, and the birds are not more than two. How do I know how many animals I have in a particular class?

Comment: You might need to refine your question. Are you putting different kinds of animals in the same cage? Or do you have different cages for different animals?

Comment: Good practice also states that you should not over-engineer your code. First, you got the naming convention for constants wrong. Second, by adding a constant you have introduced an indirection. Now you can no longer see what the method is doing without scrolling up to the `CAGELIMIT` variable. Third, the  maximum number of animals is by far a constant. What if you get a bigger cage? Fourth, you got some code duplication. Fifth, guard clauses (what @LW001 used) would be shorter here, thus more consise. Six, `getCageAnimals` does not return the animals, but the number of animals. Keep it simple.

Comment: I have different cages for different animals. For example, for Hippos this open cage and for Bird this cages with mesh.

Comment: @Wexzuq Pass the size of the cage to the constructor of the cage. Use that to initialize the cageSize variable that you use for checking the limit.